# geocouch error on nodejs

Tags: google-maps, node.js, couchdb, geospatial, cradle

I have 3 questions pertaining to geocouch on nodejs environment.

1. my code is as follows. The connection to the database is not happening and it does not print anything after "before connecting to database". what's wrong ?

   var connection = new(cradle.Connection)(settings.COUCHDB_HOST, settings.COUCHDB_PORT, 
                                           {auth: settings.COUCHDB_AUTH});

   console.log("before connecting to database");
   var db = connection.database(settings.COUCHDB_DATABASE, function(err) {
           if (err) {
               console.log("database connection problem :", err);
               throw err;
           }
           console.log("connected to iriscouch", settings.COUCHDB_HOST);
   });
2. Does geocouch support any operation other than bbox ? i mean operation like, radius, polygon ?
3. recently the function spatiallist has been changed to something. Any idea what it is ? Where can I find the latest and greatest documentation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. no idea
2. Only bounding box search is supported at the moment. More to come
3. _spatiallist changed to _spatial/_list. The README is always kept up to date: https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/#readme

Comment: great, thank you for the answer.. bbox is good for many reasons, but if you have too many data the map becomes cluttered at a higher zoom level. Also if I want to find restaurants only within 5km, data beyond 5km becomes irrelevant.